# If $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups with $H\cap K=\{e\}$, then $xy=yx$ for $x\in H, y\in K$.

Tags: group-theory

**Claim :** $H$ and $K$ are two normal subgroups of group $G$ such that $H\cap K = \{e\}$ then $ xy = yx $ for $x \in H$ and $y \in K$.

**Proof :** Let $x \in H$ and $y\in K$ then I need to prove that $xy =yx$. Let us assume that

$$y^{-1}xy \neq x$$
$y^{-1}xy = z$ where $z \in H$

**Question :** I am not getting how to proceed further?

Comment: Near duplicates [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1292029/11619), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1784612/11619). The exact dupe is closed so I'm a bit hesitant to use my dupehammer.

Comment: We have *used* this result so many time in this site that it is surprising if it has not been handled explicitly many times. Therefore there is the urge to close it as a dupe of *something* :-)

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen I am disagree with your opinion regarding closing this question.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Why? If it is not a duplicate of a non-closed and answered question, then the fact that it has been used a lot here is another reason **not** to close it as a duplicate. Then, if this question reappears again in the future (and I suppose it will), that new question will be closed as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen what about https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253131/h-1-h-2-unlhd-g-with-h-1-cap-h-2-1-g-prove-every-two-elements

Comment: A great catch @quid. Using that. Anyone wanting to add a new answer can still do so at the dupe target (or at one of the listed alternatives).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Understood. I appreciate your concern. Also, I have occasionally been closing dupes rather militantly, so use your vote when/if you disagree. I do think that quid found an ideal dupe target.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I fully agree: that's an ideal dupe target.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note $x^{-1}(y^{-1}xy) = (x^{-1}y^{-1}x)y$. The LHS is in $H$ since $H$ is normal and is a subgroup. The RHS is in $K$ since $K$ is normal and is a subgroup. So, the common value must be $e$.

Comment: We never used the finiteness of $G$, right?

Comment: I don't think anyone said $G$ was finite. But yea we didn't need to assume $G$ is finite for this argument.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\pi:G\to G/H$ be the projection. Then $\pi(x)=\pi(x^{-1})=e$
so $\pi(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})=\pi(y)\pi(y^{-1})=e$, so $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\in H$.
Similarly $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\in K$....

Answer (score 1):

You started out well. From

$$yxy^{-1}=x$$

notice that on the left you have a conjugation, which smells like a good idea to me, since one of the definitions of a normal subgroup is that it's closed under conjugation. So the left hand side is in $H$. Now continue:

$$(yxy^{-1})x^{-1}=e$$

The left hand side is a product of two elements of $H$ and so is in $H$. If we could show it's in $K$ as well, then we'd be done. But in fact, all we have to do is shuffle the parentheses around to get $y(xy^{-1}x^{-1})$ and see that the left hand side is indeed in $K$, for exactly the same reason it's in $H$. Now you can check that each of the steps in our reasoning is reversible to get back to the original equation you wanted to prove, $yx=xy$.

Another, maybe more direct way is to just calculate the "difference" between $xy$ and $yx$ and check that it's "zero" (identity). So we try to calculate $xy(yx)^{-1}$ and show it equals $e$. You should find that the reasoning is almost exactly the same.